# how to check UIButton image conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have three button images in table view cell, I would like to check the condition between them. When I click button 1 means button 3 should not work. Next condition button 3 clicked means button 1 should not work. button 2 can select in all conditions.

```
ButtonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"];
ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"];
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.tag = 1;
[button1 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

ButtonImageSelected1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eblue.png"];
ButtonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"];
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 27, 36, 36);
button2.tag = 2;
[button2 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected1 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(select_id:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button2];

ButtonImageSelected2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"];
ButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"];

button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
button3.tag = 3;
[button3 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button3 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(select_id:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button3];

-(void)select_id:(UIButton *) tempBtn {
    if (tempBtn.tag == 1) {
        [tempBtn setSelected:YES];
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button2 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected1 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button3 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempBtn setSelected:! tempBtn.selected];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please make the question clear.Your coding also not able to understand .What your requirement?

Comment: i want to check the conditions between three buttons.

Comment: in the ' select_id ' method check button tag and disable the buttons, that you don't want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code .....

u didn't set the the target of button 1 ..
 set the target of button1 then try it

hope it will work ...

Comment: i have missed to add in this stack, but in my coding i have set the target for button 1 also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector for all 3, you can add an additional method that is called for all of the common processes you will use in all three selectors. In those selectors you either put `button.enabled = true;` or `button.enabled = false;`

As an example, here is the button 1 selector.

```
-(void)button1Selector: (id)selector {
    button3.enabled = false;
    [self doOtherStuff];
}
```